# Permission Inheritance

Tags: document-library, permissions, unique

Suppose I have one document library and inside this library. I have one `Item X`.

Two groups has permission on this library,

```
Admin(Full Control)
User(Read permission)
```

I defined unique permission on `Item X` like

```
User(for read)
Editor(for Contribute)
```

I go back to library and delete the `User` group from Library, so default behavior should be on `Item X`, `User` group should be there but when checked permission on item it has vanished from item also, how?

Comment: are your sure you have broken the inheritance on item X ?

Comment: Yes ,i defined unique permission  on item x

Answer (score 0):

SharePoint groups are defined on Site Collection level, not on list level, so what you did was that you deleted the User Group from the site collection, thus it was removed from all items within that site collection.

Comment: But Jussi I didn't delete group from site collection , i am deleting group at library level.

Comment: You cannot create or delete groups on list level. You can only add/remove permissions for groups on a list level.

Comment: that the thing whenever i am removing a group on list level why permission are also removing at item level even though that item itself having a unique permission.?